# Not Detecting Input Properly

Tags: c++

I've JUST started C++ today, and I am working on an Advanced Text-based calculator. Anyways, I'm working on exponents, but when I start my program, and enter the string that starts Exponent mode, It doesn't go into expponent mode, only into the regular calculator mode. Here is my Code:

```
//
//  main.cpp
//  C++ Calculator
//  This is just a basic Calculator Application to be run through the command line.
//  v.0.02 - Second version of calculator, basic text, command line interface, loop.
//  Created by Johnny Carveth on 2013-04-17.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 Johnny Carveth. All rights reserved.
//
#include <math.h>
#include <iostream>
int int1, int2, answer;
bool bValue(true);
std::string oper;
std::string cont;
using namespace std;
std::string typeOfMath;
double a;
double b;
int answerExponent;


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    // Taking user input, the first number of the calculator, the operator, and second number.   Addition, Substraction, Multiplication, Division
    cout<<"______________________________________________\n";
    cout<<"|Welcome to The ExpCalc! Do you want to do   |\n";
    cout<<"|Exponent Math, or Basic Math(+, -, X, %)    |\n";
    cout<<"|Type in 'B' for basic Math, and'E' for      |\n";
    cout<<"|Exponential Math! Enjoy! (C) John L. Carveth|\n";
    cout<<"|____________________________________________|\n";
    cin>> typeOfMath;
    if(typeOfMath == "Basic" || "basic" || "b" || "B")
    {
        cout << "Hello! Please Type in your first integer!\n";
        cin>> int1;
        cout<<"Great! Now Enter your Operation: ex. *, /, +, -...\n";
        cin>> oper;
        cout<<"Now all we need is the last int!\n";
        cin>> int2;

        if (oper == "+") {
            answer = int1 + int2;
        }
        if (oper == "-") {
            answer = int1 - int2;

        }if (oper == "*") {
            answer = int1 * int2;
        }if (oper == "/") {
            answer = int1 / int2;
        }
        cout<<answer << "\n";
        cout<<"Thanks for Using The ExpCalc!\n";

    }else if(typeOfMath == "Exp" || "E" || "e" || "Exponent"){
        cout<<"Enter the desired Base. Example: 2^3, where 2 is the base.\n";
        cin>> a;
        cout<<"Now what is the desired exponent/power of the base? Ex. 2^3 where 3 is the exponent!\n";
        cin>>b;
        answerExponent = double (pow(a,b));
    } else(cout<<"Wrong String!");
}
```

Helpful tips only, remember this is my first day with C++. Also If it is of any help, I'm using XCode 4!

Comment: A few other tips, not related to your problem (which has already been adequately answered): pick a [brace style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style) and stick with it consistently; prefer `std::cout` (or perhaps `using std::cout`) over `using namespace std`; avoid globals unless absolutely necessarily (everything you've declared before `main` is a global); and finally, bear in mind that `int / int2` is doing *integer division*, which may give you unexpected results (it truncates anything after the decimal place, rather than rounding).

Answer (score 4):

You may want to look at your if expression

`if(typeOfMath == "Basic" || "basic" || "b" || "B")`

Each thing between the || is evaluated as a conditional.  So try something like:

```
if(typeOfMath == "Basic" || 
   typeOfMath == "basic" ||
   typeOfMath == "b" || 
   typeOfMath =="B") { 
// do basic
```

Make the same modifications for `else if(typeOfMath == "Exp" || "E" || "e" || "Exponent")`

Comment: GREAT answer fixed my problem. But now when It does the equation for exponents, I get an (lldb) error. Any clue?

Comment: @DtrollMC It might be because `answerExponent` is an `int`, and you're trying to assign a `double`?

Comment: @DtrollMC Change `answerExponent = double (pow(a,b));` to `answerExponent = static_cast<int>(pow(a,b));` but do bear in mind that you will lose all digits after the decimal point (where applicable) because you are calling a function on `double`s but storing the result in an `int`. For better results, declare `answerExponent` as a `double` and do `answerExponent = pow(a,b);`

Comment: I just tried and dont get an error... you may want to do a clean build.  Also you aren't outputting the answer in your current code.

Comment: Still get the same error, tried the static cast as well no use.

Comment: you may want to open a new question with your updated code - have you made any other changes?

Comment: He posted the new question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16071696/lldb-error-with-exponents-on-c). Looks like the problem was a missing header: `#include <string>`.