# LLDB Error with Exponents on C++

Tags: c++

I have updated my calculator code, and am adding an exponent function. However, when I try to get the answer to the equation, i get this error:
(lldb)
Any help would be greatly appreciated, as This is my first day with C++!
Yep, that's all!
Here's my code!

```
#include <math.h>
#include <iostream>
int int1, int2, answer;
bool bValue(true);
std::string oper;
std::string cont;
using namespace std;
std::string typeOfMath;
int a;
int b;
int answerExponent;


int main(int argc, const char * argv[]){

// Taking user input, the first number of the calculator, the operator, and second number. Addition, Substraction, Multiplication, Division
    cout<<"______________________________________________\n";
    cout<<"|Welcome to The ExpCalc! Do you want to do   |\n";
    cout<<"|Exponent Math, or Basic Math(+, -, X, %)    |\n";
    cout<<"|Type in 'B' for basic Math, and'E' for      |\n";
    cout<<"|Exponential Math! Enjoy! (C) John L. Carveth|\n";
    cout<<"|____________________________________________|\n";
    cin>> typeOfMath;
    if(typeOfMath == "Basic" ||
       typeOfMath == "basic" ||
       typeOfMath == "b" ||
       typeOfMath =="B")
    {
        cout << "Hello! Please Type in your first integer!\n";
        cin>> int1;
        cout<<"Great! Now Enter your Operation: ex. *, /, +, -...\n";
        cin>> oper;
        cout<<"Now all we need is the last int!\n";
        cin>> int2;

        if (oper == "+") {
            answer = int1 + int2;
        }
        if (oper == "-") {
            answer = int1 - int2;

        }if (oper == "*") {
            answer = int1 * int2;
        }if (oper == "/") {
            answer = int1 / int2;
        }
        cout<<answer << "\n";
        cout<<"Thanks for Using The ExpCalc!\n";

    }else if(typeOfMath == "Exp" ||typeOfMath == "E" ||typeOfMath == "e" ||typeOfMath == "Exponent"){
        cout<<"Enter the desired Base. Example: 2^3, where 2 is the base.\n";
        cin>> a;
        cout<<"Now what is the desired exponent/power of the base? Ex. 2^3 where 3 is the exponent!\n";
        cin>>b;
        answerExponent = (pow(a,b));
        cout<< answerExponent;
    } else(cout<<"Wrong String!");
}
```

Please help! I will probably ask a lot of questions aswell, so please dont get mad! I am also on a Mac, using Xcode 4!

Comment: Can you post the full/exact error message?

Comment: Full exact error message is (lldb) thats all I am given!______________________________________________
|Welcome to The ExpCalc! Do you want to do   |
|Exponent Math, or Basic Math(+, -, X, %)    |
|Type in 'B' for basic Math, and'E' for      |
|Exponential Math! Enjoy! (C) John L. Carveth|
|____________________________________________|
e
Enter the desired Base. Example: 2^3, where 2 is the base.
2
Now what is the desired exponent/power of the base? Ex. 2^3 where 3 is the exponent!
3
(lldb)

Comment: Just in case there is some confusion `(lldb)` is not the error text, it is the prompt for the debugger. The Low Level virtual machine DeBugger. Similar to GDB.

Answer (score 4):

Add this line to your includes:

`#include <string>`

With that done, I am able to get the code to compile and run with the correct output for 2^3, in both Visual Studio, and in GCC 4.7.2 using ideone.com ([click here](http://ideone.com/RLQTpo) to see the output). However, my compiler still emits a warning because of a conversion from `double` to `int` which you should probably attend to by casting. Change this:

`answerExponent = (pow(a,b));`

To this:

`answerExponent = static_cast<int>(pow(a,b));`

With that said, the compiler is emitting that warning for a reason, and by casting you are basically just telling the compiler to "shut up and do it anyway". A better approach is to avoid the need for a cast. Instead of doing the above change, change this line:

`int answerExponent;`

To this:

`double answerExponent;`

This makes more sense, because there is little point in calling `pow` with `double`s as arguments if you are going to throw away the fractional part of the number afterwards.

Comment: Greta thanks man! Awesome! but if i may ask, how did the #include <string> fix it?

Comment: @DtrollMC Your code is using `std::string` which is part of the `<string>` header. You must include that header any time you want to use `std::string`. I can't explain why the error message is so unhelpful though - I don't use XCode.